# OSM API Overpass

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to pull all glaciers as entered in OSM in a given country but am noticing that I am only pulling a fraction of what is available. For example, when I run this following code:

```
import overpass from shapely.geometry 
import shape, Polygon
api = overpass.API()
api = overpass.API(endpoint="https://overpass.myserver/interpreter")
api = overpass.API(timeout=600)
query = 'area["ISO3166-1"="IS][admin_level=2];(way["natural"="glacier"](area););'
result = api.get(query, verbosity='geom')
import geopandas
results = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(result['features'])
```

The result has 132 features and appears as so:

[Iceland Glaciers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyvR9.png)

I know this is missing one large glacier (Vatnajökull) which does appear in OSM under osm id 406429.

Any thoughts as to why this is not appearing as a result from my query?

Comment: Your query only includes **ways**, your example 406429 is a relation, though.

Comment: can I add relation to this query? I am having trouble appending it with the geometry

Comment: Your query should be something like https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/13zl - cannot help you with your python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSM Wiki tag documentation is a helpful starting point when writing Overpass queries. Here is the documentation for [natural=glacier](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dglacier). The tag/value is applied to *nodes* and closed *ways* based on the documentation and also appears to apply to  *relations* based on community preference (even though this is discouraged in the documentation).

To query for nodes, ways, and relations, you can use the abbreviation `nwr` instead of the union `(node[natural=glacier];way[natural=glacier];relation[natural=glacier];);`. As a side note, you can drop `admin_level=2` since ISO3166-1 codes are unique identifiers.

Here is the Python request:

```
query = 'area["ISO3166-1"="IS"];nwr[natural=glacier](area);out geom;'
response = api.get(query)
```